# Get-AzureRmServiceBusNamespace -Name

Tags: powershell, azureservicebus, azure-rm

I'm trying to use the `Get-AzureRmServiceBusNamespace` module to retrieve a specific Service Bus namespace using the `-Name` parameter.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.servicebus/get-azurermservicebusnamespace?view=azurermps-6.13.0) for this cmdlet implies that this parameter can be used to retrieve a specific namespace or group of namespaces by the resource group. When I try to do this, the response includes *all* namespaces. I have also tried using the alias for this parameter (`NamespaceName`). What is interesting is that the `-ResourceGroupName` parameter does narrow down the results. I can retrieve the specific ServiceBus by piping the output to the `Where-Object` cmdlet with a filter on the `Name` property, but that feels kludgey.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `Gets a description for the specified Service Bus namespace within the resource group.` - I think what this means is that you need to provide both `-ResourceGroupName` and `-Name` parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This command essentially calls different REST APIs when you pass different parameters.

If you just run it without any parameter i.e. `Get-AzureRmServiceBusNamespace`, it will list all the namespaces in the subscription, i.e. call the API [`Namespaces - List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/stable/namespaces/list).

If you pass the resource group name, it will list all the namespaces in the resource group i.e. call [`Namespaces - List By Resource Group`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/stable/namespaces/list-by-resource-group).

So in your case, if you want to get a specific namespace, you need to pass the resource group and namespace name, i.e. call [`Namespaces - Get`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/stable/namespaces/get).

```
Get-AzureRmServiceBusNamespace -ResourceGroup <resourceGroupName> -NamespaceName <namespaceName>
```

**Besides**, the old `AzureRM` module has been deprecated, I recommend you to use the new [`Az`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-6.1.0) command [`Get-AzServiceBusNamespace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.servicebus/get-azservicebusnamespace?view=azps-6.1.0) instead.